# is it possible to edit the links in get started with your site webpart

Tags: 2013, web-part, office-365

There is a webpart called "get started with your site" in media and content category

Is it possible to edit the links that are predefined in it?

Comment: I bet you can do this with jQuery in the worst case :)

Comment: yeah, I wanted to check if there is way out of the box :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible OOB for `GettingStartedWebPart`, because all links for this web part are hard-coded in the code.

The only possible "workaround" is to create Promoted links list with a similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

create Promoted links list with a similar behavior

[image]

go to Site Contents > New (plus button) > choose App

create new list as Promoted link then

[image: create new list as Promoted link]

create your links and set your images as icon there.

this is my result:

[image]

this is source: link : [promoted link in sharepoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/promoted-links-app-in-sharepoint-2013/)